# FTP, download files by wildcard search criteria

Tags: ftp, search

I need to download a series of files over ftp on a command line. The server I am downloading from has a folder structure which is like so:

```
/path/to/file1/abcfile111def
/path/to/file1/abcfile222def
/path/to/file1/abcfile187def
/path/to/file1/abcfile139def
/path/to/file1/abcfile209def
```

I know that it is possible to use `mget` to download multiple files and the potential of wildcards but I need to apply a bit of search criteria to the download.

The search criteria is that from a given directory I am in when connected from the server I want to search all sub directories from that folder and look for files and apply a search criteria which looks for the following strings:

```
file100,file101,file102....file199
```

The string criteria will look for files which match this range of numbers. How can I go about doing this?

If a solution is only possible through programming I am quite proficient with python so that won't be a problem in terms of finding an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I crafted this solution using bash code:

```bsh
for i in /path/to/file1/*/*;
do 
    if [[ ${i##*[[:alpha:]]} =~ [[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]] ]]
    then 
         echo $(realpath "$i")
    fi
done
```

This matches the three digits (101, 102, 103..., 199) in the file name. Replace the `echo` command with your `ftp` command for each file matched. Please test with `echo` command and run when okay.

The path is important, as `/path/to/file1/*` won't search as it contains subdirectories with subdirectories, so the search path should be `/path/to/file1/*/*`. Please change accordingly.